# What is Badlock and how does it work?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft, samba

A while back there was an announcement for the disclosure of a security vulnerability named "Badlock" - [including this fancy name and a logo](http://badlock.org/).

The disclosure date was today and I was surprised (and shocked) to read that the attack would allow an attacker to gain administrative privileges for an active directory controler.

**How can an attacker gain administrator access by exploiting Badlock?**, or formulated slightly differently: **How does badlock work?**

Bonus question: How could I mitigate it if there was no patch?

Comment: It's been patched and relies on a MITM attack to complete. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-047

Comment: Why downvote this question for whoever did it?  It's a perfectly legitimate, well crafted question.

Comment: @BradBouchard No idea. I upvoted it since I haven't seen any other questions on sad^Wbadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badlock was massively overhyped and, it turns out, the  name has nothing at all to do with the vulnerability (it has nothing to do with bad locking, mutexes, or anything of the sort). It requires a man-in-the-middle attack to carry out, and allows an attacker to execute arbitrary Samba network calls using the context of the intercepted user. The attacker will gain read and write access to the SAM database and will have access to password hashes, which they can use to elevate privileges.

The vulnerability is [CVE-2016-2118](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-2118). According to its description page:

> The MS-SAMR and MS-LSAD protocol implementations in Samba 3.x and 4.x before 4.2.11, 4.3.x before 4.3.8, and 4.4.x before 4.4.2 mishandle DCERPC connections, which allows man-in-the-middle attackers to perform protocol-downgrade attacks and impersonate users by modifying the client-server data stream, aka "BADLOCK."